# how can i verified if a path exist or not

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I would like  to test if a path like this file:///c:/folder/texts/int.txt is exist or not if it's exist i open it else echo"file doesn't exist" ,somone have any idea please?

Comment: There are *thousand* of duplicates https://www.google.ca/search?q=php+tell+if+file+exists&oq=php+tell+if+file+exists&aqs=chrome..69i57.2923j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=php+how+can+i+verified+if+a+path+exist+or+not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very short google search shows http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

`bool file_exists ( string $filename )`